# Is it possible to highlight the first instance of words in a row of columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Example:

**Tom**
Tom
Tom
**Bill**
Bill
**John**
John
**Michael**
Michael
**Steve**
Steve
Steve
Steve

Comment: (1) Will the cells with the same name always be grouped together?  (2) If the answer is “yes”, this is very easy.  Even if it’s “no”, it’s not very hard.  Please try to solve this yourself.  If you get stuck, let us what you tried and where you got stuck.  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the data occupies A1:A13.

Cell A1 is always bold. Format it unconditionally.

Switch addressing view to R1C1 style. Select another (A2:A13) data cells. Select "Conditional formatting - By formula". Enter the formula

```
=ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,R1C1:R[-1]C1,1,FALSE))
```

Set conditional format as bold text.

That's all.